# Flask development server not working with Python 3.7

Tags: flask, python-3.7

I am learning Flask and ran into an issue when running Flask 1.0.2 and Python 3.7 on Windows 10.

Firstly the output shown when starting the flask server is minimal and also I could not start flask in development mode...

I then switched to Python version 3.6 all works as expected...

Can Flask be used with Python 3.7?

More info is shown below:

I have a simple flask service set up as per the below:

```
# /services/users/project/__init__.py

from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.from_object('project.config.DevelopmentConfig')  

@app.route('/users/ping', methods=['GET'])  

def ping_pong():  
    return jsonify({   
        'status': 'success',  
        'message': 'pong!' 
    })
```

A manage.py file is used to start this app:

```
# services/users/manage.py

from flask.cli import FlaskGroup

from project import app

cli = FlaskGroup(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

I ran the below to start the app:

```
set FLASK_APP=project/__init__.py
python manage.py run
```

The app started and the following was printed in the console which contains less information than I was expecting:

```
 * Serving Flask app "project"
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

I then stopped the app and tried to start it in 'development' mode:

```
set FLASK_ENV=development
python manage.py run
```

This displayed the exact same 'running' message in the console...

```
 * Serving Flask app "project"
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

I was scratching my head at this point and checked to make sure that FLASK_ENV was set correctly:

```
C:\PROJECTS\flask_app1\services\users>echo %FLASK_ENV%
development
```

I then switched my Python version to v3.6 and repeated the same steps as above...

When running in production mode I saw the below (expected) output in the console which gives more information on how Flask is running than the same command run using Python 3.7:

```
c:\PROJECTS\flask_app1\services\users>python manage.py run

Serving Flask app "project/__init__.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

I then set `FLASK_ENV=development` and saw the below (expected) output:

```
c:\PROJECTS\flask_app1\services\users>set FLASK_ENV=development

c:\PROJECTS\flask_app1\services\users>python manage.py run
 * Serving Flask app "project/__init__.py" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 344-776-722
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

So my question is can Python 3.7 be used to develop and serve Flask applications or is Python version 3.6 the latest supported version - or has something changed in Python 3.7 in terms of how Flask works/displays status messages?

Comment: What is in `manage.py`? Why are you not using the `flask` command?

Comment: Also, what Flask version is installed in either place, how did you install Flask? If `flask` works, then `flask --version` will tell you what Flask version was installed, as well as Python version info.

Comment: Flask 1.0.2, Python 3.6.6

Comment: @MartijnPieters - thanks for getting back to me - I've updated the question to include the manage.py file content. I am running Flask 1.0.2 and it seems that the server doesn't allow me to run in 'development' mode when using Python 3.7

Comment: So, is Python 3.7 also running Flask 1.0.2? Do you have any `.env` file in the directory, is the `dotenv`  package installed in either Python? Python 3.7 is *not special* here, something else is different.

Comment: Okay, I'm an idiot :-)  Python 3.7 is running 'Flask 0.12.2' - I am not using a .env and I have not installed dotenv - so I think the 'issue' stems from the different flask versions between the python versions... Thanks for your help - I am learning and this was useful - should I delete the question or answer it myself in case it may be helpful to other newbies?

Comment: Right, yes, I was scanning the [`flask/cli.py` annotated history](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blame/master/flask/cli.py) to see in what version the `Environment` banner was introduced. Had you used the `flask` command-line script instead of a custom `manage.py` you'd have discovered earlier that the command wasn't there.

Comment: Your question is currently closed because it is lacking enough detail to be answerable. I'm not sure that having installed an older library version is all that interesting for future users.